# How to fix Bash on an older MacOS

Tags: bash

I am still running MacOS 10.6.8 on my older iMac because of software issues-some of my most useful stuff won't run on systems past Tiger.  Can I use the patch published by Justin Meyers in "Every Mac Is Vulnerable to the Shellshock Bash Exploit: Here's How to Patch OS X" on my Mac?

Comment: FYI : If you don't offer web services to the public internet from your Mac you don't "need" to update your bash.

Comment: Well yeah, but you have to understand what you're doing. Otherwise, you'll just make more trouble for yourself than you otherwise would have. See also: http://tenfourfox.blogspot.com/2014/09/bashing-bash-one-more-time-updated.html